# Value not refreshing after second ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call and rendering out a shopping cart with jQuery.

```
function show_cart() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions/show-cart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
    })

    .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.cart, function (index, item) {

            var showCart = `

                <div class="row hr marg-b-30 marg-t-30">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marg-b-30">
                            <img src="uploads/${item.pic_name}" alt="${item.product_name}" class="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 marg-b-30">
                            <a href="#" class=""><b>Product</b></a><b class="right">R${item.price}</b>
                            <p class="">${item.product_name}</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-xs bg-color--second removeItem" data-id="${item.item_id}" data-itr="${item.i}">Remove <i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 marg-b-30">
                            <div class="input input-counter">
                                <div class="input__helper pos-left pointer input-counter__plus cartPlus" data-itr="{$i}">
                                    <i class="material-icons ico-xs"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="text-center" readonly="" value="${item.each_item}">
                                <div class="input__helper pointer input-counter__minus">
                                    <i class="material-icons ico-xs"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marg-b-30 text-right text-left-xs">
                            <span class="price-xs">R${item.subtotal}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;

            $(".somediv").append(showCart);


        });

        $("#total").append(data.total);
        $("#subtotal").append(data.total);


    })

    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Each item in the cart has it's one remove/delete button and when a user clicks that, it calls my delete function which removes that item from the cart (fades out). I then make an ajax call to the same show-cart.php script that initially displays the cart hoping that this will update the subtotal and total values but they stay the same as before removing the cart item. How can I get the total to update?

Here is the delete item or remove from cart function:

```
function remove_item() {

    $("body").on("click", ".removeItem", function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var indexToRemove = $(this).data('itr');
        var div = $(this).parents("div.hr");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/show-cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                indexToRemove: indexToRemove
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(div).html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'>");
                $("#total").empty();
            },
        })

        .done(function (data) {
            $(div).fadeOut();
            $( "#total" ).html(data.total);//This gives me the same total as before I removed the item

        })

        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
        })
    })
} // END REMOVE ITEM
```

show-cart.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {

    $itemsInCart = 0;

} else {

        $featured = "Yes";
        $cartTotal = "";
        $i=0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];

            $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `product_name`, `price`, `pic_name` FROM `products` as `p` INNER JOIN `product_images` as `pi` ON p.`id` = pi.`product_id` WHERE p.`id` = ? AND `featured` = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("is", $item_id, $featured);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $numRows = $result->num_rows;
            if($numRows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $product_name = sanitize($row['product_name']);
                    $price = sanitize(money_format('%.2n', $row['price']));
                    $subtotal = money_format('%.2n', $each_item['quantity'] * $price);
                    $pic_name = $row['pic_name'];
                    $cartTotal = $subtotal + $cartTotal;
                    $quantity = $each_item['quantity'];

                    $cart_details[] = array(

                    "product_name" => $product_name,
                    "price" => $price,
                    "subtotal" => $subtotal,
                    "pic_name" => $pic_name,
                    "each_item" => $quantity,
                    "subtotal" => $subtotal,
                    "item_id" =>$item_id,
                    "i" => $i

                    );

                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }



    $response['total'] = $cartTotal;
    $response['cart'] = $cart_details;
    echo json_encode($response);
}


if(isset($_POST['indexToRemove']) && $_POST['indexToRemove'] !== "") {

        $key_to_remove = $_POST['indexToRemove'];
        if(count($_SESSION['cart_array']) <=1) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
        } else {

            unset($_SESSION['cart_array']["$key_to_remove"]);
            sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you get this `data` that returns `show-cart.php`? from database?

Comment: yes, the product ID is used to fetch the rest of the product info from a database.

Comment: have you tried  `console.log(data.total)` in ajax done callback? it changes?

Comment: If I console.log it out, data.total is exactly the same as before I removed the item from the cart i.e.: same as when I first load the cart. If I remove a second item, the total then changes to what it should have been after removing the first item.

Comment: can you show your `show-cart.php`?

Comment: Sure, I updated my original question with the php

Comment: Try to disable ajax cache

Comment: @gaetanoM, thank you for your suggestion. How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and no difference. `$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   url: 'functions/show-cart.php',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {
    indexToRemove: indexToRemove
   },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should unset items from session before returning ajax response. Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['indexToRemove']) && $_POST['indexToRemove'] !== "") {

            $key_to_remove = $_POST['indexToRemove'];
            if(count($_SESSION['cart_array']) <=1) {
                unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
            } else {

                unset($_SESSION['cart_array']["$key_to_remove"]);
                sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
            }
        }    

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {

        $itemsInCart = 0;
        $response['total'] = 0;
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {

            $featured = "Yes";
            $cartTotal = "";
            $i=0;
            foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
                $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];

                $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `product_name`, `price`, `pic_name` FROM `products` as `p` INNER JOIN `product_images` as `pi` ON p.`id` = pi.`product_id` WHERE p.`id` = ? AND `featured` = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("is", $item_id, $featured);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $numRows = $result->num_rows;
                if($numRows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $product_name = sanitize($row['product_name']);
                        $price = sanitize(money_format('%.2n', $row['price']));
                        $subtotal = money_format('%.2n', $each_item['quantity'] * $price);
                        $pic_name = $row['pic_name'];
                        $cartTotal = $subtotal + $cartTotal;
                        $quantity = $each_item['quantity'];

                        $cart_details[] = array(

                        "product_name" => $product_name,
                        "price" => $price,
                        "subtotal" => $subtotal,
                        "pic_name" => $pic_name,
                        "each_item" => $quantity,
                        "subtotal" => $subtotal,
                        "item_id" =>$item_id,
                        "i" => $i

                        );

                        $i++;
                    }
                }

                $stmt->close();
            }



        $response['total'] = $cartTotal;
        $response['cart'] = $cart_details;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: Ahah, now we are getting somewhere. This works perfectly if I only have 2 items in the cart. As soon as I have 3 and remove the last one, something goes horribly wrong and in console it shows the second last item with it's total.

Comment: try to comment out this line `sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);`

Comment: It was the sort() function that was messing me about. I removed that and all is good

Comment: One last thing please. When I remove all items from the cart I get an error but it isn't really a helpful description. I tried this but it doesn't resolve my issue. `if(data.total < 1) {
    
   alert("cart empty");
    
   } else {
    
    $( "#total" ).html(data.total);
   }`

Comment: The error just says parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. This is in console

Comment: you should return something when `$_SESSION['cart_array']` dosn't exist

Comment: Yeah, I am trying that now but obviously it isn't right. I tried to set the response to equal 0. `$response['total'] = 0; ` if the session is not set which it isn't as when the cart is empty it is unset. `if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {`

Comment: look at my updates after `if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {`

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to json_encode() it, that's why it wasn't working!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help